# Directive in angularJS google maps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i'm trying to create google maps markers that consume an API that gets all the data needed for the marker to be shown in the map, however, I also want to pass a directive for the popup content, but the directive controller never gets fired. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code is kind of hard to get where is the problem, but try doing the following

1. Consume the API in a service and store the data there
2. Use the service inside the directive binding its vars to the html.